# Get Installed software list

Tags: c#, c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get Installed software list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5909589/get-installed-software-list)

How to get installed application software list using C? I have a solution in C#. This is the C# code:

```
System Microsoft.Win32 
private string Getinstalledsoftware() {
    string Software = null; 
    string SoftwareKey = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"; 
    using (RegistryKey rk = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(SoftwareKey)) { 
        foreach (string skName in rk.GetSubKeyNames()) { 
            using (RegistryKey sk = rk.OpenSubKey(skName)) { 
                try { 
                    if (!(sk.GetValue("DisplayName") == null)) { 
                        if (sk.GetValue("InstallLocation") == null) 
                            Software += sk.GetValue("DisplayName") + " - Install path not known\n";
                        else 
                            Software += sk.GetValue("DisplayName") + " - " + sk.GetValue("InstallLocation") + "\n"; 
                    } 
                } 
                catch (Exception ex) { 
                }
            }
        } 
    } 
    return Software; 
}
```

How can I convert the C# code into C code?

Comment: Why convert it to C if you have a working solution in C#?

Comment: we don't use c# code in our project.could you please help out.

Answer (score 2):

You need to map the operations performed here to their corresponding Windows API [registry functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724875%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and other [string manipulation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f0151s4x.aspx) functions if you wish to perform the translation.

Otherwise you could probably use the [Windows Installer API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372860%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to do this directly.

Here's an example that dumps the products using the installer API:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Msi.h>

static UINT msierrno;

#define PRODUCT_NAME_SIZE 512
#define INSTALL_LOCATION_SIZE 512

int main(void)
{
    DWORD index;
    TCHAR productCode[39];
    for (index = 0; (msierrno = MsiEnumProducts(index, productCode)) == ERROR_SUCCESS; index++)
    {
        TCHAR productName[PRODUCT_NAME_SIZE];
        TCHAR installLocation[INSTALL_LOCATION_SIZE];
        DWORD productNameSize = PRODUCT_NAME_SIZE;
        DWORD installLocationSize = INSTALL_LOCATION_SIZE;

        wprintf(L"product code: %s\n", productCode);
        if ((msierrno = MsiGetProductInfo(productCode, INSTALLPROPERTY_INSTALLEDPRODUCTNAME, productName, &productNameSize)) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
            /* handle error */
        }
        else wprintf(L"\tproduct name: %s\n", productName);
        if ((msierrno = MsiGetProductInfo(productCode, INSTALLPROPERTY_INSTALLLOCATION, installLocation, &installLocationSize)) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
            /* handle error */
        }
        else wprintf(L"\tinstall location: %s\n", installLocation);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

p.s., you'll need to link to the msi.lib/dll library.

Answer (score 1):

You could e.g.:

1. Use [.NET Reflector](http://reflector.red-gate.com) to see how the registry functions are actually implemented, then
2. Take a look at the Microsoft [Registry Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724875%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to use them in C/C++.

Of course you can also directly move to step 2 without step 1.